# How to connect to InterBase database using c#

Tags: c#, interbase

I have a need to connect to a report Interbase server and pull data from a table.
I have the following code, I am trying several options to make a successful connection to the server, however not able to do so. Could you please let me know what's wrong with my code. Or please point me to any article which shows a step by step approach to successfully connect to an Interbase server and pull data.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using InterBaseSql.Data.InterBaseClient;

string connectionString = "server=remoteserver_ip_address;dataBase=C:\\test\\interbasedb\\database.gdb;User_Name=myusername;Password=mypassword;";
using (var connection = new IBConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (var command = new IBCommand("select * from table rows 1", connection, transaction))
        {
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                    reader.GetValues(values);
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|", values));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect the issue is with the connection string. I tried changing the connection string several ways, but getting different error every time.
All errors below.

1. Client library - ibclient64 not found (I copied ibclient64.dll into the project folder, and this error was resolved)
2. Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a InterBase login.
3. connection rejected by remote interface
4. Unable to complete network request to host "remoteserver_ip_address". Failed to locate host machine. Undefined service gds_db/tcp.

I am able to connect to the same server using **IBConsole** application, Which I believe is a client software to connect to Interbase server (Like Management Studio for SQL Server, and WorkBench for MySQL and PGAdmin for PostgresSQL)

The Parameters I am using to connect to the Interbase Server using IBConsole are same as that of I am using in the C# code.

Report Server IP: **remoteserver_ip_address**
DataBase: **C:\test\interbasedb\database.gdb**
User Name: **myusername**
Password: **mypassword**

[image]

> Partial breakthrough for above issue.

After several hours of trial and error, I was finally able to connect to the interbase server successfully using **Embarcadero** drivers.
I had to change the connectionstring to look as below for a successful connection.

**server=remoteserver_ip_address;database=C:\test\interbasedb\database.gdb;user=myusername;password=mypassword**

But now I am stuck with another issue. When I use a query like **select * from some_table_which_doesnot_exists**, I clearly receive a message that the **Table is not found**.

And when I use a query like **Select * from a table_that_exists_in_the_db**, I always get follow error.

- Dynamic SQL Error
- SQL error code - 804
- SQLDA error (I believe SQLDA = SQL DataAdapter, because thats where the code it throwing error)

I went to the [Embarcadero Error Codes List](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/2020/en/SQLCODE_Codes_and_Messages) to see more information on this error and found the reason to be  **SQLDA missing or incorrect version, or incorrect number/type of variables.**. I am stuck here not sure how to proceed further. Please help.

Comment: Does InterBase have a server process running on the remote machine you're connecting to? It's highly unusual to be attempting to route to a file system path when connecting to a remote machine for a database.

Comment: Actually I am new to Interbase, I have previously work with SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, this is the first time I am working on Interbase. I am able to connect to the server using IBConsole application (See the Image Above), but when I try from C# code I am getting errors.

Comment: [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/interbase/) seems to indicate that you need to prefix the "database" string with "ComputerName:" ?

Comment: Fildor, Can you please explain or provide a sample connection string

Comment: Just have a look into the link and find the driver you are using.

Comment: @Fildor, no luck. Can you provide an example. I am using **InterBaseSql.Data.InterBaseClient** which is not in the list

Comment: @VIRIYALANARESH, did you find any solution to your problem? Looks like there is not good support for Interbase with C#

Comment: yup, not solution yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing "PORT" details for connection to the interbase server instance.

You can try the below solution for the connection string. This has worked for me in my local machine.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cs = BuildConnectionStringBuilder().ToString();
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new IBConnection(cs))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    using (var command = new IBCommand("select * from employee rows 1", connection, transaction))
                    {
                        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                var values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                                reader.GetValues(values);
                                Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|", values));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        
    }
private static IBConnectionStringBuilder BuildConnectionStringBuilder()
    {
        var builder = new IBConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.UserID = "SYSDBA";
        builder.Password = "masterkey";
        builder.DataSource = "localhost";
        builder.Database = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "test-employee.ib";
        builder.Port = 3050;
        return builder;
    }
```

Comment: I was able to connect to the server using my code (the server uses default port, hence I did not mention it in the connect string). The error I am facing is pulling the data after the connection is opened. No matter what query I execute I always get the same error.     **Dynamic SQL Error                                                                                               
SQL error code - 804                                                                                          
SQLDA error (I believe SQLDA = SQL DataAdapter, because thats where the code it throwing error)**

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

namespace WinFormsApp1_3grupa
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
SqlConnection konekcija = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

```
    private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void buttonIzadji_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sqlUpit = "select * from Citalac";
        try
        {
            SqlCommand komanda = new SqlCommand(sqlUpit, konekcija);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(komanda);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem(row["HotelID"].ToString());
                listItem.SubItems.Add(row["Naziv"].ToString());
                listItem.SubItems.Add(row["Adresa"].ToString());
                listItem.SubItems.Add(row["Telefon"].ToString());
                listItem.SubItems.Add(row["Grad"].ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(listItem); // Dodaje red u ListView
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Greska");
        }
    }

    private void buttonPrikazDGV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@param1";
        param.Value = numericUpDown1.Value;

        string sqlUpit = "select * from Hotel where HotelID=@param1";
        SqlCommand komanda = new SqlCommand(sqlUpit, konekcija);
        komanda.Parameters.Add(param);
        try
        {
            konekcija.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = komanda.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Greska");
        }
        finally
        {
            konekcija.Close();
        }
    }

    private void buttonPrikazLV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sqlUpit = "select * from Hotel";

        try
        {
            SqlCommand komanda = new SqlCommand(sqlUpit, konekcija);


            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(komanda);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem(row["HotelID"].ToString());
                listItem.SubItems.Add(row["Naziv"].ToString());
                listItem.SubItems.Add(row["Adresa"].ToString());
                listItem.SubItems.Add(row["Telefon"].ToString());
                listItem.SubItems.Add(row["Grad"].ToString());
                listItem.SubItems.Add(row["Drzava"].ToString());
                listItem.SubItems.Add(row["Kategorija"].ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(listItem); // Dodaje red u ListView
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Greska");
        }
    }

    private void buttonIzadji2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).